# IE11 child <div> tag overflowing at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, tags, internet-explorer-11

I have a parent `<div>` tag and it's child `<div>` tag.

The height of the child `<div>` tag is dynamic and varies depending upon certain logic.

The height of the parent `<div>` tag should also vary depending upon the height of the child `<div>` tag and this is happening in browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but not in `IE11`. This is making the UI look like the child `<div>` tag is going beyond the parent `<div>` tag at the bottom of the page.

**My question is-** Is there a way I can make sure that child `<div>` tag remains within the boundaries of the parent`<div>` tag?

**UPDATE: adding css...**

```
.child {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F6F6F6;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    min-height: 749px;
    background-color: white;
    display:table;
    float:right;
    min-width: 900px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    height:100%;
}

.parent {
    overflow: visible;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 13px 25px 75px 25px;
    min-width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a DEMO link ?

Comment: It would have been great if you can share the piece of code, so that it can be seen - what css you have applied on both (parent & child) DIVs.

May be due to some CSS attribute there is browser compatibility issue. Only inspectable after you show the URL or the piece of code. Thanks

Comment: Will add the style..

Comment: I have added the CSS in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set .parent height to auto not 100%, i.e:

```
.parent {
    overflow: visible;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 13px 25px 75px 25px;
    min-width: 900px;
}
```